# scape compilation error vba

Tags: vba, compiler-errors, powerpoint

I am creating a vba code that should be compatible from office 2007. But the problem is that I get a compilation error in office 2007 in this peace of code:

```
       For j = 1 To vNum
            If sh.name = videoN(j).name Then
                If sh.MediaFormat.VideoCompressionType = videoN(j).MediaFormat.VideoCompressionType Then
                    videoNumber = j
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        If videoNumber = 0 Then
            vNum = vNum + 1
            videoNam = "media" & vNum
            Set videoN(vNum) = sh
        Else
            videoNam = "media" & videoNumber
        End If
        If curPresentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowMediaControls Then
            control = "true"
        Else
            control = "false"
        End If
```

The compilation error happens on this lines:

```
If sh.MediaFormat.VideoCompressionType = videoN(j).MediaFormat.VideoCompressionType Then
```

and

```
If curPresentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowMediaControls Then
```

In office 2007 those options doesn't exist that is why it is giving me the error but for office 2010 and 2013 I need to have those options. Is there any way to scape this compilation error?

I can put an if statement to let it enter to those lines only when the version is higher that office 2007 but it will give anyway the compilation error when it enters to this module.

Answer (score 0):

Dim them as object and use

```
 set obj = createobject("blah")
```

See my post from earlier today.

[VB6 program fails opening Excel 2007 with Automation Error Library not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029484/vb6-program-fails-opening-excel-2007-with-automation-error-library-not-registere/25029961#25029961)

Comment: Or in this case, Dim sh as Object